# Storybook : How to inject Vue Custom Element styles

Tags: vue.js, storybook

I have a Vue 3.2 Custom Elements project, perfectly running via -ce extension and webpack config

```
`chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => ({
        ...options,
        compilerOptions: {
          // treat any tag that starts with ion- as custom elements
          isCustomElement: tag => tag.startsWith('ce-')
        }
      }))
  }`
```

But, once a component is added to Storybook, the `style` part on my Single File Components does not get injected in Shadow DOM. No style at all (unless javascript imported from separate .css file).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the same problem, has to do with how vue handles styles in a Custom Element (.ce.vue) file. Will post answer here if I ever get it working.

Comment: Any luck with this one? Not finding much info online about thisi ssue

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone having the issue with vite. I had to move the scss out of the component and into a separate scss file and `import './button.scss'` in the script area of the .ce.vue component.

Not ideal as it loses `scoped` but at least it's working in storybook.